# How to start from a non-initial NavigationController scene

Tags: ios, swift, uinavigationcontroller, segue, xcode-storyboard

I'm trying to mimic the navigation logic in Apple default app "Photos". Below is the illustration of the app navigation logic.

[image]

When you first start the app, you land on "Moments" view which is at the third highest hierarchy level in the app. It's quite interesting because the whole "Photos" tab seems like to be embedded into a single NavigationController.

However, if all scenes are embedded into a single NavigationController how do you start from a non-initial scene?

Here's my hackish implementation without embedding scenes into any NavigationController(all the segues are presented as `show`:
[image]

It results the behavior I wanted but I'm not sure about the memory issue. Am I allocating new VCs every loop? And the storyboard just doesn't look right.

As an answer, a simple Storyboard capture with brief explanation would be nice.

Comment: using `UINavigationController` you can set the `.viewControllers` array = to your `[firstViewController,SecondViewController,DesiredInitialViewController]`

Comment: You can do this programatically, can be this a solution for you?

Comment: My app is made with storyboard and I want to be consistent in methods and styles. Is this not possible to do it in storyboards?

Comment: I don't know if is another way for do this, the only I know is using the .viewControllers property programatically, If you want I can provide an answer

Comment: @ReinierMelian I implemented it programmatically thanks to your advice. If you want credits then please provide an answer with details so other people can understand easily as well. If I don't see your answer within a week then I will do it myself.

Comment: I will post an answer about this ASAP @YOUNG

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As I said in my comments you need to modify the `.viewControllers` property of your `UINavigationController` you can do this using `setViewControllers(_:animated:)` method or modifying directly `.viewControllers` property where `rootViewController` will be the `viewControllersArray[0]` and `topViewController` will be `viewControllersArray[count-1]`

This property description and details can be founded in the `UINavigationController` documentation

```
viewControllers
```

> Property
>
> The view controllers currently on the navigation stack.

**Declaration**
**SWIFT**

```
var viewControllers: [UIViewController]
```

> **Discussion** The root view controller is at index 0 in the array, the back view controller is at index n-2, and the top controller is at
>   index n-1, where n is the number of items in the array.
>
> Assigning a new array of view controllers to this property is
>   equivalent to calling the setViewControllers:animated: method with the
>   animated parameter set to false.

**example**

```
    let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: Bundle.main)
    let firstViewController = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "FirstViewController") as? FirstViewController
    let secondViewController = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "SecondViewController") as? SecondViewController
    let thirdViewController = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "ThirdViewController") as? ThirdViewController

    self.navigationController?.setViewControllers([firstViewController,secondViewController,thirdViewController], animated: false)
```