# Navigation Back shows other Viewcontroller during the transition

Tags: ios, objective-c, uinavigationcontroller, navigation

I have three Viewcontrollers : ViewControllerA, ViewControllerB and ViewControllerC.

When I am in **ViewControllerC**, I click on Navigation **Back** button to go back to ViewControllerA directly, skipping **ViewControllerB**.

I have tried following approaches, both of them work. But, I wonder while transiting from ViewController C to ViewController A, it shows ViewController B in one second for during the transition.

Is there a way just directly navigate from ViewController C to ViewController A skipping ViewControllerB.

**Approach 1:**

```
-(void) viewWillDisappear:(BOOL)animated {
   if ([self.navigationController.viewControllers indexOfObject:self]==NSNotFound) {
      NSLog(@"back button pressed");
      [self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:YES];
   }
  [super viewWillDisappear:animated];
}
```

**Approach 2:**

```
-(void) viewWillDisappear:(BOOL)animated {
    if ([self.navigationController.viewControllers indexOfObject:self]==NSNotFound) {
        NSLog(@"back button pressed");
        //[self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:YES];
        NSMutableArray *allViewControllers = [NSMutableArray arrayWithArray:[self.navigationController viewControllers]];
        for (UIViewController *aViewController in allViewControllers) {
            if ([aViewController isKindOfClass:[ViewControllerA class]]) {
                [self.navigationController popToViewController:aViewController animated:NO];
            }
        }
    }
    [super viewWillDisappear:animated];
}
```

Comment: Have you heard of Unwind Segue? If you're using storyboard, go through [this](https://spin.atomicobject.com/2014/10/25/ios-unwind-segues/)

Comment: [self.navigationController popToRootViewControllerAnimated:YES];

Comment: can you show your back button code ?

Comment: I am using Navigation back button item.

Comment: did you have an example that you can put on github to reproduce your error? @hotspring

Comment: unfortunately not, it is a part of big project.

Comment: no, sorry I will put an answer now, its a common problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use `setViewControllers` method, and pass only the viewControllerA that is the first element in your `navigationController.viewControllers` array

**Code**

```
- (IBAction)backAction:(id)sender {
    UIViewController * viewControllerA = [self.navigationController.viewControllers firstObject]; //we get the first viewController here
    [self.navigationController setViewControllers:@[viewControllerA] animated:YES];
}
```

similar answer here [How to start from a non-initial NavigationController scene](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46002976/how-to-start-from-a-non-initial-navigationcontroller-scene/46108664#46108664) but in swift

[image]

Comment: that logic also shows `ViewControllerB` during the transition from `ViewControllerC` to `ViewControllerA`. I do not want to display `ViewControllerB`

Comment: I will review then give me a minute @hotspring

Comment: Have you created `BarButtonItem` or have you used Navigation Back Button?

Comment: Did you put the logic directly in the `backAction`??? if you put the logic in `viewWillDisappear` will show you the viewControllerB @hotspring

Comment: you need to create a barButtonItem @hotspring and use a backAction on your own

Comment: cannot I able to use `viewWillDisappear` without using BarButtonItem?

Comment: yes but in `viewWillDisappear` my logic don't work @hotspring

Comment: Adding Left BarButton programatically will be overridding Navigation Back button?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/165355/discussion-between-reinier-melian-and-hotspring).

Comment: any idea https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48981920/tabbar-delegate-method-is-not-getting-called-after-changing-storyboard

Comment: @hotspring as soon as I can I will review your question buddy

Answer (score 0):

Try `popToRootViewControllerAnimated` . It will move to First ViewController which NavigationController embed.

```
[self.navigationController popToRootViewControllerAnimated:YES];
```

Comment: that does not solve my problem. It still shows all the viewcontrollers during the transition back to `rootViewcontroller`.

Answer (score 0):

```
        NSArray *arrayViewControllers = [self.navigationController viewControllers];


        for (UIViewController *viewcontroller in arrayViewControllers) {
            if ([viewcontroller isKindOfClass:[ViewControllerA class]]) {
                [self.navigationController popToViewController:viewcontroller animated:true];
            }
        }
```