# Tabbar delegate method is not getting called after changing storyboard

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitabbarcontroller

I have **login** and **signup** viewcontrollers in Login storyboard not in the Main storyboard.

Once signup or login is successful, then I am changing Login storyboard to Main. The following code works but when I select any tab, it does not call tab delegate method in the **AppDelegate**

However, if user is already succesfully signup or logged in, then it calls the following tabbar delegate method.

**LoginViewController.m**

```
if(isLoginSuccess)
{
    UIStoryboard *mainStoryboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main" bundle:nil];
    CustomTabBarViewController *tbc = [mainStoryboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"tabbar"];
    tbc.selectedIndex = 2;
    [self presentViewController:tbc animated:YES completion:nil];
}
```

**AppDeletage.m**

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {
    CustomTabBarViewController *tabBarController = (CustomTabBarViewController *)self.window.rootViewController;
    tabBarController.delegate = self;
    return YES;
}

-(void) tabBarController:(UITabBarController *)tabBarController didSelectViewController:(UIViewController *)viewController
{
    if (tabBarController.selectedIndex == 2) {
        if(![self isRegistered])
        {
            UIStoryboard *loginStoryboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"LoginStoryboard" bundle:nil];
            UIViewController *vc = [loginStoryboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"LoginViewController"];
            [ROOTVIEW presentViewController:vc animated:YES completion:nil];
        }
        else
        {
            tabBarController.selectedIndex = 2;
        }
    }
}
```

**Update :**

AppDelegate is not getting called but I wonder why the following code does not open Loginstoryboard in the AppDelegate after user is logout.

```
#define ROOTVIEW [[[UIApplication sharedApplication] keyWindow] rootViewController]


UIStoryboard *mainStoryboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"LoginStoryboard" bundle:nil];
UIViewController *vc = [mainStoryboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"LoginViewController"];
[ROOTVIEW presentViewController:vc animated:YES completion:nil];
```

Answer (score 3):

Please find below code.

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {
    UIStoryboard *main = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main" bundle:nil];
    UITabBarController *tabController = [main instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"TabbarController"];
    tabController.delegate = self;
    return YES;
}

-(void) tabBarController:(UITabBarController *)tabBarController didSelectViewController:(UIViewController *)viewController{
    NSLog(@"Selected Index - %lu",(unsigned long)tabBarController.selectedIndex);
}
```

On ViewController's Button Click Method,

```
- (IBAction)btnLoginTapped:(id)sender {
    UIStoryboard *main = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main" bundle:nil];
    UITabBarController *tabController = [main instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"TabbarController"];
    tabController.selectedIndex = 1;
    [self presentViewController:tabController animated:YES completion:nil];
}
```

then on **Main.storyboard**, Drag **Object** from the **Object Library** and put it below **First Responder** in Tab bar Controller Scene, Set the **Object class to AppDelegate**, then right click on Tab Bar Controller and **set delegate to that Object Class** as shown in below image.

[image]

Let me know it is working or not, I'm ready to help with the solution.